# How can I check if the first character of a string it is a number as a condition in *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, type-conversion, frontend

I am trying to check if a document name it is coming with the first char as a number. I am not able to make my code go in and display "Dummy string". I tried with this two options but it is not working.

```
1.
let documentPDF = "6487954.pdf"
<ng-container *ngIf="Character.isDigit(ParseInt(documentPDF.charAt(0))) == false">
         Dummy string
</ng-container>

2.
let document = "6487954.pdf"
<ng-container *ngIf="isNaN(ParseInt(documentPDF.charAt(0))) == false">
         Dummy string
</ng-container>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you need to do all that logic in the template itself?

Comment: Yes, I need to do that check directly on the template

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression:

try this:

```
let documentPDF = "6487954.pdf"

<ng-container *ngIf="!/^\d/.test(documentPDF)">
  Dummy string
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I received "Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 2 in [!/^\d/.test(documentPDF)]". Thank you for your try!